# Closing Fancybox after an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, fancybox

I open a form with fancybox and I throw some AJAX functions when I click submit. I request to refresh a table on my main page and after I close fancybox.

When I click the submit button for the first time after the first load of my main page, everything is functional, but if I try to recall my form and submit two or more times, the fancybox.close () not working not. Here is my code:

```
$('#bouton_ajout_terminal').fancybox({
href: 'http://www.myurl.com/emm/utilisateurs/form_ajout_mobile.php',
type: 'ajax',
wrapCSS: 'fancybox-custom',
closeClick:false,
openEffect:'elastic',
openSpeed:200,
closeEffect:'elastic',
closeSpeed:200,
helpers:{
    overlay:{
        css:{'background-color':'#eee'}
    }
},
afterShow: function() {
    $('#formulaire_ajout_mobiles').on('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.reponse == 'ajout ok') {
                    refresh_terminaux(),
                    $.fancybox.close();
                } else {
                    alert('Erreur : '+ json.reponse);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
  }
});
```

There is something weird because my table on my main page refreshes itself well whenever I submit my form which proves that my function is operational. The only thing that does not work once it is fancybox.close ().

Comment: Is `refresh_terminaux()` a function you are calling before closing fancybox? I just wonder if you have to close it with a semicolon `refresh_terminaux();` instead of a comma since it is not an ajax setting... or try adding an alert after that function to check if subsequent functions are executed. Additionally, you can also try `$.fancybox.close(true);`

Comment: I tried with the ; and $.fancybox.close(true); . The result is the same :( And yes refresh_terminaux() is a function to refresh a table on a main page's div. First time i submit my form, all is working but not the second time :(

Comment: One last try: if you are using fancybox v2.0.6+ then try `beforeShow` instead of `afterShow`

Comment: The result is the same with beforeShow. It works but only the first time.